# Mostrar mensaje cuando no se actualizo la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario que actualiza un registro en una base de datos. (Funciona correctamente).
El problema es que cuando no se cumple la condicion `where` me muestra Actualización correcta aunque no se actualiza.

Como hago para que cuando no se actualice me diga que no se actualizo

```
<form method="POST" action="update.php">
  <label for="pedido"># Pedido</label>
  <input type="text" name="pedido" id="doc">
  <label for="texto">Valor abono</label>
  <input type="text" name="pagoabono"  id="texto">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar abono" name="btn_abono">
</form>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['btn_abono'])) {
   include("abrir_conexion.php");
   $pedido    = $_POST[ 'pedido' ];
   $pagoabono = $_POST[ 'pagoabono' ];
   $conex = mysqli_connect($host,$usuariodb,$clavedb,$basededatos);
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Fallo la conexion: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  mysqli_query ($conex, "UPDATE $tabla_db1 SET pagoabono ='$pagoabono' where pedido= '$pedido'")
  or die("No se actualizo");
  include("cerrar_conexion.php");
  echo("Actualizacion correcta");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Me temo que siempre se va a cumplir, ya que tu ECHO no esta condicionado, podrías usar una sentencia para saber si obtienes algo de la base con ese where y en base a ello sabrías si hacer el echo o no.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. la verdad manejo poco el tema, podria hacer una búsqueda y si arroja resultados hacer el update?. cual seria la forma mas sencilla de hacerlo?

Comment: Claro, la idea sería que si tienes resultados con tu búsqueda el update cumplirá la condición del where, y con ello disparar tu echo. Pero, no creo que sea lo mas optimo, ya que haces dos consultas a la base, lastimosamente no domino PHP por lo que fue mas un comentario que una respuesta a tu pregunta. Pero la idea te la dejo.

Answer (score 2):

necesitas obtener las filas afectadas, puedes hacerlo con:

```
mysqli_affected_rows($conex);
```

solo verifica que las filas afectadas sean mayores que 0, el numero de filas afectadas es el numero de registros que se actualizaron, si las filas afectadas son 0 quiere decir que ninguna fila cumplió con el `where` así que no se actualizaron.

```
mysqli_query ($conex, "UPDATE $tabla_db1 SET pagoabono ='$pagoabono' where pedido= '$pedido'")
  or die("No se actualizo");
  if (mysqli_affected_rows($conex)>0){
     echo("Actualizacion correcta");
  } else {
     echo("Pedido no encontrado");
  }
  include("cerrar_conexion.php");
```

Ademas debes de tener en cuenta que tu query es suceptible a ataques de inyeccion SQL, intenta darte una vuelta por:

[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 1):

Te muestro un ejemplo de actualización usado MySQLi.

El código está explicado en los comentarios.

Básicamente los pasos serían, una vez obtenida la conexión.

1. Escribir la consulta, aplicando el criterio de consultas preparadas para [prevenir la Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967).
2. Asignar en variables los valores que se van a usar en la consulta
3. Preparar la consulta mediante `prepare`
4. Evaluar si la preparación tuvo éxito. Puede no tener éxito si por ejemplo escribes un nombre de tabla que no existe o cometes errores de sintaxis en la consulta
5. Si la preparación es correcta, haces `bind` de los valores que quieres actualizar. De ese modo los valores viajan separados de la instrucción SQL en sí, por lo que la Inyección SQL se dificulta, *casi* se evita. Digo esto porque nada es 100% seguro.
6. Ejecutas la consulta y evalúas al mismo tiempo el resultado de la ejecución. `execute` devolverá `true` si la ejecución fue exitosa, entonces podrás mostrar un mensaje con la cantidad de filas afectadas por el update, usando para ello `affected_rows`
7. Cierras los recursos de lugar.

**Nota:** Los datos de tablas y columnas fueron puestos para prueba en el demo, debes sustituirlos por los tuyos.

Espero te sirva.

**código**

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uu3z-gdy9)**</kbd>

```
<?php

    require "util/public_db_info.php";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);

    /*
        * Las consultas preparadas sustituyen los valores reales
        * por signos de interrogación en MySQLi
    */

    $sql = "UPDATE books   SET title=? WHERE id=?";    

    /*
        * Almacenar en variables los datos a usar
        * Cambia las variables puestas a mano 
        * por las variables tuyas
    */
    $titulo= "Gracias a la vida";  
    $id= 2;         

    //Preparar la consulta
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

    //Evaluar si  la preparación tuvo  éxito

    if ($stmt){
         /*
           * Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
           * la letras "si" indican el tipo de cada dato que se va a insertar
           * s: String, si es una cadena , i: Integer, si fuera un entero, etc
           * Ejecutar
        */

        $stmt->bind_param("si", $titulo,$id);

         /*
           * Verificar el resultado de la ejecución
           * sabiendo que, en el caso de UPDATE, como en el caso 
           * de INSERT, $stmt devuelve TRUE si fue exitosos
        */


        if ($stmt->execute()) {

        /*
          * Imprimir la cantidad de filas actualizadas usando affected_rows
        */

        printf("%d Fila(s) actualizada(s).\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "No se pudo actualizar";
        }

        /*
         * Cerrar $stmt para liberar recursos
        */

        $stmt->close();

    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Hubo un error preparando la consulta";
    }

         /*
         * Cerrar conexión a la bd para liberar recursos
        */


    $mysqli->close();


    ?>
```

**resultado**

```
1 Fila(s) actualizada(s).
```