# ¿Donde utilizar $stmt->close() & $stmt->free_result() - MySQLi PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Cuando existe más de una consulta en un mismo archivo muestra errores, todo lo soluciono mediante `$stmt->close();`

Se me presento la duda de cual es la forma correcta de su uso, cuantos `close()` se debe utilizar.

El `$stmt->free_result()` cumple la misma función si se utiliza, ya no se debe utilizar `close()` o si se utiliza `close()` ya no se debe utilizar `free_result()`

**¿Me pueden explicar?**

```
  if ($stmt->fetch()) {
     echo "Resultados";
    } $stmt->close();
     else {
       $stmt->close();
       echo "No existe resultados";
    }
```

y

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  echo "Resultados";
}
$stmt->close();
 else {
  $stmt->close();
  echo "No existe resultados";
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero expliquemos la diferencia entre ambos:

[`$stmt->free_result()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.free-result.php) libera la memoria relacionada con un conjunto de resultados, mientras que [`$stmt->close()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.close.php) libera la memoria relacionada con una consulta preparada. Posteriormente, al llamar `$stmt->close()` se cancelará cualquier resultado que quede.

Básicamente, llamar a `$stmt->close()` proporcionará el mismo efecto que invocar a `$stmt->free_result()` ya que también cancela el conjunto de resultados. Pero al invocar `$stmt->free_result()` no se borrará la memoria utilizada por la declaración preparada, en cuyo caso debe usar `$stmt->close()`.

En cuanto a cuál usar, puede haber situaciones en las que pretendas usar la declaración preparada que has inicializado, pero ya no necesites el conjunto de resultados que tienes actualmente. En tal caso, llamarías a `$stmt->close()` cuando hayas terminado con la declaración preparada (puedes pasar valores diferentes a una misma consulta preparada... esa es una de sus ventajas) y, en su lugar, llamarías a `$stmt->free_result()` antes de ejecutar otra instrucción.

- Fuente: [$stmt->close() vs $stmt->free_result() en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2417834/5587982)

### Respondiendo concretamente a tu pregunta

En el ejemplo de código que pones, si observas en el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), el código viene escrito así:

```
 $consulta = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 150,5";

/*Antes  de hacer cualquier cosa con $stmt se verifica que no sea falso*/
/*$stmt sería false si hay algún error al llamar el método prepare*/
/*Todo lo que se hace con $stmt se hace dentro de este bloque*/
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($consulta)) {

    /* ejecutar la sentencia */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* vincular las variables de resultados */
    $stmt->bind_result($nombre, $código);

    /* obtener los valores */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $nombre, $código);
    }

    /* cerrar la sentencia */
    $stmt->close();
}

 /*Si hay un error preparando la consulta y aquí escribes $stmt->close()*/
 /*Tendrás el error: Exception: Call to a member function close() on boolean*/
 /*Porque $stmt sería false, no la representación de una consulta preparada*/

/* cerrar la conexión a la BD*/
$mysqli->close();
```

Este código lo que hace es liberar el `$stmt` al salir del bucle. Al cerrar `$stmt` no es necesario usar free.

Tú pones además un ejemplo de código usando `if`... pero con `fetch` los datos deben ser leídos dentro de un bucle, ya que al leerlos dentro de un simple `if` no podrás obtener todos los resultados, en caso de que haya más de una fila.

En resumen: Si usas `close` al terminar de usar tu consulta preparada y tus datos, sería suficiente. Si quieres usar `free_result` antes de `close`, úsalo. Hay debates sobre si es vital o no su uso. Según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18747905/5587982) el uso de `free_result` no aporta nada. Puedes hacer una prueba con `memory_get_usage()` en varios escenarios y determinar si realmente aporta algo. Según la misma respuesta, su uso no es vital.

Comment: pero que sucede cuando existe un `else` en `while ($stmt->fetch()) {}` en `else` también se debe utilizar `close`

Comment: Es que no sé lo que quieres evaluar en ese `if...` antes del `while`. Yo lo que hago es, antes del `while`  evaluar si el `$stmt` es correcto, si lo es, entro en el while, leo los datos y cierro el stmt al salir del while, si no lo es, imprimo un mensaje de error diciendo que el stmt no se pudo preparar. Ejemplo: `if($stmt) {while {//leer datos aquí } $stmt->close(); //cerrar $stmt al salir del bucle while }else{echo "No se preparó el stmt";}` Mira por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/80587/29967), es un `UPDATE` pero sirve para cualquier consulta preparada.

Comment: solo he puesto dos ejemplos muy comunes que he visto, otro muy común que he observado es:  `$stmt->fetch();` ***pero a `$stmt->fetch();` no se puede añadir una respuesta en caso de falso o si***  te pregunto es si es necesario añadir un `close` en los `else` así como los ejemplos de la pregunta, porque he visto que también lo añaden será porque también esta dependiendo de una respuesta de la consulta como un mensaje de error, esas es mi duda mayor.

Comment: Si la preparación falla, `$stmt` será **false** por lo que no podrás hacer nada con él. Fíjate que el ejemplo del Manual hace esta evaluación `if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($consulta)) {` el código sólo entrará ahí si el `prepare` funciona y es **sólo ahí dentro donde se cierra `$stmt`**. Si tú intentas cerrarlo fuera de ahí tendrás un error: **`Exception: Call to a member function close() on boolean`**. Lo puedes probar creando una consulta errónea y luego intentando cerrar el `$stmt` sin evaluarlo. Si tuviera tiempo te crearía un código de prueba pero ahora mismo no puedo.

Answer (score 0):

Ninguno de los métodos que funcionas pertenecen a PDOStatement (lista de metodos [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php)) sin embargo si te refieres al metodo`PDOStatement::closeCursor` y a la función `mysql_free_result`.

Ambas liberan la memoria pero la primera es cuando usas PDO y la otra cuando usas cuando usas el api de mysql el cual esta obsoleto.

`PDOStatement::closeCursor` debes usarlo cuando en una consulta  no recorres todo el resultado y deseas ejecutar otra consulta, cuando la consulta es muy grande y deseas liberar la memoria utilizada, cuando deseas reutilizar el `PDOStatement`.

Los ejemplos que pones no son validos ya que la estructura del if y del while es incorrecta.

```
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
 echo "Resultados";
} $stmt->close(); // error de sintaxis en estructura de if y $stmt no tiene el metodo close es closeCursor()
 else {
   $stmt->close(); //$stmt no tiene el metodo close es closeCursor()
   echo "No existe resultados";
}

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  echo "Resultados";
}
$stmt->close(); 
 else { // No es un if el else esta de mas y close no existe
  $stmt->close();
  echo "No existe resultados";
 }
```

Lo ideal seria:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  ...
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

y

```
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
  ...
}
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Utiliza siempre closeCursor nunca esta de mas. y esas serian las formas que te recomiendo.

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta no se refiere ni a PDO ni a la obsoleta extensión mysql*, sino que se refiere a Mysqli. Sería bueno que el OP editase la pregunta poniendo la etiqueta de la extensión que está usando, de eso modo no habría confusión en las respuestas.

Comment: @A.Cedano actualizado :) esto existe en mysqli `closeCursor();`

Comment: Mil disculpas no paso por mi mente que fuera mysqli. Según el manual de php el metodo free_result se usa cuando para liberar l memoria de un conjunto de resultados guardado por http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php por l