# ¿Cómo cerrar una conexión de mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Si abrí una conexión para insertar datos en una base de datos con

```
$conn = new mysqli($HOST, $USUARIO, $PASSWORD, $DB);
```

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de cerrar la conexión al finalizar mi script?

Comment: si estas realizando sentencias preparadas de `mysqli` lo realizas así `$stmt->close();` puedes ver más preguntas planteadas aquí mismo sobre el mismo tema, [observe la siguiente respuesta y pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111158/donde-utilizar-stmt-close-stmt-free-result-mysqli-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La información del [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.close.php) es muy pobre sobre el cierre de conexiones mysqli. Ni siquiera indica el modo de hacerlo usando el estilo orientado a objetos. De hecho, la conexión se puede cerrar de dos maneras.

### A. Estilo Orientado a Objetos

```
$conn->close();
```

### B. Estilo por procedimientos

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Si quieres tener un código coherente, sin mezclar estilos, recomendaría que uses la opción **A.**, ya que al crear la conexión usaste el estilo orientado a objetos:

```
$conn = new mysqli($HOST, $USUARIO, $PASSWORD, $DB);
```

La mezcla de estilos es considerada una mala práctica.

También es importante señalar que el Manual indica esto en una nota:

> `mysqli_close()` no cerrará las conexiones persistentes. Para más
>   detalles, véase la página del manual sobre [conexiones
>   persistentes](http://php.net/manual/es/features.persistent-connections.php).
>
> <sub>[Cierre de conexiones mysqli en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.close.php)</sub>

Comment: Excelente respuesta. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -2):

Usa la función integrada

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Deberías explicar el motivo por el que piensas que tu respuesta soluciona el problema