# ¿Cómo pasar de mysql a mysqli?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

tengo problemas con unas sentencias de MySQL, soy nuevo en PHP y no se como pasar unos códigos a mysqli ya leí la documentación pero no me queda muy claro.

Tengo PHP 7.4 al ser esa version ya no funciona mysql_query() por ejemplo.

Como puedo pasar a mysqli?

Los codigos son:
Login.php

```
 $query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");

    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)

    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
```

y este otro

Register.php

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows==0)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
        (full_name, email, username,password)
        VALUES('$full_name','$email', '$username', '$password')";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Como comente soy un novato y solo intente agregar la "i" al final y saltan los siguientes errores

En el login

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/path/public_html/index.php on line 26

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/path/public_html/index.php on line 28
```

En el registro

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/path/public_html/register.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/path/public_html/register.php on line 24

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/path/public_html/register.php on line 32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que es preciso entender es que `mysqli` tiene **dos estilos**: el estilo llamado *procedural* (más antiguo si se quiere), basado en funciones y el estilo *orientado a objeto* (más moderno), basado en objetos.

El estilo *procedural* se distingue fácilmente porque las llamadas son siempre así: `mysqli_funcion($parametros)`, y el estilo *orientado a objetos* también se distingue con claridad, porque las llamadas son así: `$objeto->metodo($parametros)`  o bien `$objeto->propiedad`.

En el Manual de PHP siempre hay ejemplos basados en ambos estilos cuando se explican cada una de las funciones de mysqli. E incluso puedes mezclar estilos, **pero esto no es recomendable ([ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/121711/29967))**, siempre es bueno tener rigor y claridad en el código.

Ya que hablamos de migrar código, yo te recomendaría aprovechar para **dar el paso definitivo al estilo orientado a objetos**, porque es hacia donde tiende la programación moderna. De hecho, [algunas funciones de mysqli son ya obsoletas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/436317/29967).

De todos modos te mostraré la forma de migrar el código en ambos estilos.

### Migración según el estilo procedural

Para pasar a `mysqli`  en el modo procedural, sólo tienes que agregar la `i` a las funciones.

O sea:

- Cambiar `mysql_query` por **`mysqli_query`**
- Cambiar `mysql_num_rows` por **`mysqli_num_rows`**
- Cambiar `mysql_fetch_assoc` por **`mysqli_fetch_assoc`**
- ... etc ...

Como ves, es una forma bastante simple y por eso mucha gente la prefiere. Pero como dije antes, este estilo de programación es más antiguo, produce código más extenso y podrías estar usando algunas funciones declaradas ya obsoletas.

Los bloques de código que indicas quedarían migrados haciendo esto simplemente:

#### `Login.php`

```
#Se pasa la conexión como 1er parámetro
$query =mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    {
    // ...
    }
```

#### `Register.php`

```
$query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($numrows==0)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
        (full_name, email, username,password)
        VALUES('$full_name','$email', '$username', '$password')";
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    //  ... etc ...
```

**NÓTESE** que había errores en tu forma procedural. Cuando llamas a `mysqli_query` debes pasar en primer parámetro la conexión (que aquí he asumido que se llama `$mysqli`).

### Migración según el estilo Orientado a Objetos

#### `Login.php`

```
/*
    $mysqli es el objeto conexión 
    y query() es un método de ese objeto
    Eso es lo que significa la llamada $mysqli->query()
    La llamada al método query() devuelve un objeto mysqli_result
    que en este caso quedará referenciado en $query
*/

$query=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

/*
    $query es un objeto mysqli_result 
    y num_rows es una propiedad de ese objeto
    Eso es lo que significa la llamada $query->num_rows
*/
$numrows=$query->num_rows;
if($numrows!=0)
{
    while($row=$query->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
    // ...
    }
```

#### `Register.php`

```
$query=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows=$query->num_rows;

if($numrows==0)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
        (full_name, email, username,password)
        VALUES('$full_name','$email','$username','$password')";
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    //  ... etc ...
```

La forma de conectar también varía, pero no te puedo decir nada al respecto porque no muestras tu código de conexión. De todos modos aquí hay alguna pregunta con respuestas que explican cómo migrar la conexión.

### Dar seguridad al código

Aparte de la cuestión de migrar el código, una de las mayores ventajas de pasar a mysqli es poder usar **consultas preparadas**. De hecho, tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Por tanto, no podrías quedarte tranquilo con un código *migrado* de esta manera.

Ya que vas a actualizar todo tu código, te recomiendo que empieces a usar también consultas preparadas. Así estarías escribiendo un código sin agujeros de seguridad. Además las consultas preparadas son más rápidas.

Te muestro el código migrado implementando esta práctica. Solamente lo hago en el estilo orientado a objetos, para no extenderme demasiado, además esta parte de la respuesta es un extra.

#### `Login.php`

```
/*
    a) En las consultas preparadas se ponen marcadores (?)
    en vez de los valores directamente
    b) Se usa prepare() en vez de query()
    c) Y los datos se pasan con bind_param()
    ¿Por qué todo esto? Porque un hacker podría manipular
    los datos que van en las variables y construir
    una instrucción dañina. Y dañina quiere decir
    desde robar, modificar datos o archivos hasta pasar
    cuaquier tipo de programa malicioso.

*/

$sql="SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username=? AND password=?";
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
/* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
/* ejecutar la consulta */
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
/*
    Hay que reconocer que en mysqli la obtención de resultados
    Es un poco más complicada. Es mejor escribir explícitamente
    en el SELECT las columnas que quieres usar 
    y luego usar bind_result

while($row=$stmt->fetch()) 
{
    // ... si usas bind_result aquí obtendras los valores
}

/* cerrar sentencia */
$stmt->close();
```

#### `Register.php`

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usertbl WHERE username=?";
$query=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
/* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

/* ejecutar la consulta */
$stmt->execute();

/* ligar variables de resultado */
$stmt->bind_result($numrows);

/* obtener valor */
$stmt->fetch();

/* cerrar sentencia */
$stmt->close();

if($numrows==0)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
        (full_name, email, username,password)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?"); 
    $stmtInsert=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmtInsert->bind_param("ssss", $full_name, $email, $username, $password);
    $stmtInsert->execute();

    //  ... etc ...
    $stmtInsert->close();
```

Espero que esto ayuda a clarificar el problema. Ante cualquier duda, lee primero la documentación de PHP, allí está todo bien explicado, en castellano y con abundamentes ejemplos. Y si tienes alguna duda puedes preguntar también aquí.

Cualquier cosa que no hayas entendido en esta respuesta, puedes preguntar en comentarios al pie de la misma.

Comment: Gracias @a-cedano Tu respuesta fue la solución, el sistema no es un sistema crítico por lo cual no había tanto inconveniente por las inyecciones SQL, sin embargo me gusta aprender y lo integre como me mencionaste, Gracias por toda tu ayuda.